# React router with 2 entry points

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm attempting to implement the ability for devs to create new pages using react, whilst maintaining compatibility to work alongside a master page template we use for all pages ( Includes filters, tabs etc )

What I require is the ability to render a Navigation component into 1 div, with the page content ( App ) being rendered into another ( illustrated below )

[image]

My current solution involves rendering the 2 components separately, but where I'm struggling is how to bridge the router between the two. I'm having issues where the Router has 2 instances ( Which I would understand why from the code ), but I'm unsure how I could structure this to achieve my desired behavior.

How am I able to render these components into 2 separate root divs, but have them still share history and navigation route changes be reflected to the app component?

```
import React } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import ContactPage from './ContactPage';

const HomePage = () => <div> Home page </div>;
const AboutPage = () => <div> This is an About Page </div>;

const Navigation = () => (
    <div>
        {/* Match structure of legacy tab structure, we then just replace current with a react component for navigation */}
        <li className="dropdown" id="tab-menu-li">
            <ul className="nav nav-tabs" id="tab-menu-list">
                <li className="text-left">
                    <Link to={`/home`}>home</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="text-left">
                    <Link to={`/about`}>Contact Us</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        {/*  Renders into tab-menu-li fine if I put the switch in here
        <Switch>
            <Route path={`/home`} exact component={HomePage} />
            <Route path={`/about`} exact component={ContactPage} />
        </Switch>
        */}
    </div>
);

const App = () => (
    <Switch>
        {/*  How can I make this App component, catch the route changes from navigation?
             This component draws fine, and /contact etc will work on page load. But any route changes triggered in navigation are never reflected here
        */}
        <Route path={`/home`} exact component={HomePage} />
        <Route path={`/about`} exact component={AboutPage} />
    </Switch>
);

render(<BrowserRouter><Navigation /></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('tab-menu-li'));
render(<BrowserRouter><BaseLayout /></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('dataContainer'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create two different apps and share the same history object you need to create your router manually and provide the history object kind you would like to use. Both the BrowserRouter and HashRouter does this for you (hence the names Browser and Hash routers). But you can use Router and provide it with a history object.

```
// history.js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory({
  /* pass a configuration object here if needed */
});

render(<Router history={browserHistory}><Navigation /></Router>, document.getElementById('tab-menu-li'));
render(<Router history={browserHistory}><BaseLayout /></Router>, document.getElementById('dataContainer'));
```

Comment: Awesome, that's just what I'm after works a charm, Thanks!